# Freemarker - Adding values to hash

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to add values to HashMap in my Freemarker template. I'm also using BeanWrapper so that I can see exposed methods from my Java objects.

In my data model, I have a HashMap:

```
root.put("myName", new HashMap());
```

As I mentioned above, Im using BeanWrapper so that I can use all the methods of my Java objects:

```
BeansWrapper wrapper = new BeansWrapper();
wrapper.setExposureLevel(0);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);//cfg = new Configuration();
```

Now in my template file (test.ftl) I'm trying to invoke put method of HashMap (that I've stored in data model..above):

```
${myName.put["fname:John"]}
```

This last line does not work, and I'm getting an error:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. myName.put evaluated instead to freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel on line 16, column 11 in test.ftl.
```

Could you tell me, how I can invoke `put` method of my HashMap in template file?

Comment: For what reason do you need put variables into the HashMap?  I'm just wondering, because perhaps there is a better approach.

Comment: Andy, I was going through the documentation and found below statement at http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html :- The Collection-s and Map-s of the model should be allowed to be modified during template execution. (DefaultObjectWrapper prevents that, since it creates a copy of the collections when they are wrapped, and the copies will be read-only.).. Following this, I was trying to see how the collections and the Maps can be modified from template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read about [Object Wrappers](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html).

I also like [this question](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_question_14) from the FAQ,  from which I will now quote,

> "Maybe you should push some
>   calculations back to the data-model
>   building phase. Ideally the data-model
>   contains what should be displayed, and
>   not something that serves as the base
>   of further calculations." - http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_question_14

If you need the variable in the data model, don't bother putting it in a map, use the [assign directive](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_assign.html).

Alas, I understand that the world is not perfect, and sometimes we must do what we can.

If you must, I suggest building an object to wrap your Map, i.e

```
class MapWrapper
{
        Map map = new HashMap;
        ...
       public void put(Object arg)
       {
            map.put(arg);
       }
}
```

Then simply put your map wrapper into your model, and you should be able to call put like any other method.